# Attempting to create a queue - issue with crashing C++

Tags: c++, arrays, queue

For my data structures course I have to create a queue that takes input from a .dat file, and organizes it based on high priority (ONLY if it's 1) and low priority (2 3 4 or 5).  There must be two queues, * indicates how many to service (or remove).  The .dat file looks like:

```
R 3
T 5
W 1
A 4
* 3
M 5
B 1
E 1
F 2
C 4
H 2
J 1
* 4
* 1
D 3
L 1
G 5
* 9
=
```

Here's the main.cpp

```
int main ()
{
    arrayQueue myHigh; //creates object of arrayQueue 
    arrayQueue myLow; //creates another object of arrayQueue


    while(previousLine != "=") //gets all the lines of file, ends program when it gets the line "="
    {
        getline(datfile, StringToChar);  
        if (StringToChar != previousLine)
        {
            previousLine=StringToChar; //sets previousline equal to a string
            number = StringToChar[2]; //the number of the data is the third line in the string
            istringstream ( number ) >> number1; //converts the string to int
            character = StringToChar[0]; //the character is the first line in the string            

        }

        if (number1 == 1) //if number is 1, sends to high priority queue
        myHigh.addToQueue(number1);          
        else if (number1 == 2 || number1 == 3 || number1 == 4 || number1 == 5) //if number is 2 3 4 or 5 sends to low priority queue
        myLow.addToQueue(number1);

    }
    datfile.close();
    system ("pause");
}
```

And here's the array class:

```
void arrayQueue::addToQueue(int x)
{
     if (full() == true)
     cout << "Error, queue full \n";
     else {
     fill = (fill+1)%maxSize;
     queueArray[fill] = x;
     cout << x << endl; //testing that number is actually being passed through
     count++;
     size++;
     }
}
```

However, the output that I get is just:

```
3
5
```

and then it crashes with no error.

I'm not sure where I should go, I haven't created two objects of a class OR used a file to read data before in C++.  Did I do that correctly?  I think it's just feeding 3 and 5 into the high priority queue, even though it's not supposed to do that.

Comment: `number1 == 2 || 3 || 4 || 5` doesn't do what you think. You have to compare on each number instead ( `number1 == 2 || number1 == 3 ... `.

Comment: Thanks for that, I missed that as well.  It is still crashing at the same spot, no idea what it could be!

Comment: It's asking quite a lot of participants on SO to work through all your code (there's quite a lot of it). To make things easier for us you need to make sure that we can copy and paste it and compile it. This isn't possible because, e.g., you've left out the `arrayQueue` declaration. Ideally, copy and paste everything into a single file (h files first obviously), with some additional comments to say which file is which. Then anyone who wants to help can simply copy and paste from your post into their IDE of choice. *Even better* would be for you to isolate a small fraction of failing code.

Comment: Also, narrow down your code to the snippets you believe the problem is. You posted too much code to read and understand.

Comment: Your Constructor of the `arrayQueue` class does **not** set any of the class members. instead of creating a local variable `int fill = -1` you should do `this->fill = -1` ;)

Comment: I edited out quite a bit of code, hopefully that narrows it down a bit.  I know if I remove those snippets it does not crash.

Comment: Sounds like you haven't tried using a debugger.  You can run in gdb and have a look at the stack (`bt` command) and that will probably help you quite a bit.

Comment: @TheOneAndOnly and actually, that should be `: fill(-1)` in the currently non-existant initializer list. Thats what they're for.

Comment: I fixed the constructor and cleaned up some of the code and now it doesn't crash!  You guys are too smart.  Now to make it handle more features :)

Answer (score 0):

Because output is typically buffered you may not be seeing all of the output before your program crashes. From my examination of your code, I would expect it to crash when it reaches the last line of the input file, because StringToChar is of length 1 and you are accessing the StringToChar[2]. Well, maybe not crash, but certainly get garbage. I'm not sure if string would raise an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Your processing of the read lines is certainly not quite right. First of all, you don't check whether you could successfully read a line but input should always be checked **after** you attempted to read it. Also, if the input is `=` you actually treat the value as if it is a normal line. Your basic input should probably look something like this:

```
while (std::getline(datFile, StringToChar) && StringToChar != "=") {
    ...
}
```

Given that your "string" `number` actually contains exactly one character, it is a little bit of overkill to create an `std::istringstream` (creating these object is relatively expensive) and decode a `char` converted to an `std::string`. Also, you actually need to check whether this operation was successful (for your last line, for example, it fails).

Converting a single `char` representing a digit to a string can be done using something like this:

```
if (3 <= StringToChar.size()
    && std::isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(StringToChar[2])) {
    number1 = StringToChar[2] - '0';
}
else {
    std::cout << "the string '" << StringToChar << "' doesn't have a digit at position 2\n";
    continue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think "adipy" is close, but...

```
getline(datfile, StringToChar);
```

First, you should check the return value to make sure a string was returned.

Second, if we assume that `StringToChar` equals `=`, then
`(StringToChar != previousLine)` is `true`.

Then `StringToChar[2];`, <<<<< access violation.  array is only two characters long.

Also, you might be trying to enter the last `previousLine` twice.